# Material use custom property of Object

Tags: properties, custom-properties

I have a lot of objects that I want to use the same material, but set (animate) a single custom property of each object which will be used for the material setting of each individual object.

If I create a custom property on my object(s), then copy and paste that as a driver into the material (value) - the pasted driver requires me to specify a specific object. Therefore, every object that uses this material would be driven from *that* specific object.

Is there a way I can make the driver use the property of "whatever object" the material is being applied to?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Attribute node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html) can be used to access custom properties of the current object from a material.

Set the *Type* to "Object" and put the name of the custom property in *Name*. For example, this will use the custom property "prop" to change the Base Color of the material.

[image: Attribute node with Name "prop" used with a ColorRamp for Base Color]